# JavaScript enumerator?

Tags: javascript

I want to define a list of constants that have continuous integer value, for example:

```
var config.type = {"RED": 0, "BLUE" : 1, "YELLO" : 2};
```

But it's boring to add a `"XX" : y` every time I need to add a new element in it.
So I'm wondering is there something like `enumerator` in C so I can just write:
`var config.type = {"RED", "BLUE", "YELLO"}` and they are given unique integer value automatically.

Comment: @ngen maybe I didn't make it clear. I'd like to refer to type like this: config.type.RED or config.type.BLUE, not config.type[0]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could also try to do something like this:

```
function Enum(values){
    for( var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i ){
        this[values[i]] = i;
    }
    return this;
}
var config = {};
config.type = new Enum(["RED","GREEN","BLUE"]);
// check it: alert( config.type.RED );
```

or even using the arguments parameter, you can do away with the array altogether:

```
function Enum(){
    for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i ){
        this[arguments[i]] = i;
    }
    return this;
}
var config = {};
config.type = new Enum("RED","GREEN","BLUE");
// check it: alert( config.type.RED );
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use an array:

```
var config.type =  ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLO"];

config.type[0]; //"RED"
```

Comment: This also lets you do `config.type.indexOf('BLUE'); // 1` to get the reverse if you already have the colors and need to find the index value.

Comment: @daybreaker, that should be true as well

Comment: maybe I didn't make it clear. I'd like to refer to type like this: config.type.RED or config.type.BLUE, not config.type[0]

Answer (score 2):

Use an array (`[]`) instead of an object (`{}`), then flip the array to swap keys/values.

Answer (score 2):

Define the Enum:

```
var type = {
  RED: 1,
  BLUE: 2, 
  YELLO: 3 
};
```

get the color:

```
var myColor = type.BLUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could make a function that accepts an Array:

```
function constants( arr ) {

    for( var i = 0, len = arr.length, obj = {}; i < len; i++ ) {
        obj[ arr[i] ] = i;
    }
    return obj;
}


var config.type = constants( ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLO"] );

console.log( config.type );  // {"RED": 0, "BLUE" : 1, "YELLO" : 2}
```

---

Or take the same function, and add it to Array.prototype.

```
Array.prototype.constants = function() {

    for( var i = 0, len = this.length, obj = {}; i < len; i++ ) {
        obj[ this[i] ] = i;
    }
    return obj;
}


var config.type = ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLO"].constants();

console.log( config.type );  // {"RED": 0, "BLUE" : 1, "YELLO" : 2}
```

Comment: can't you do that 1st function using the `arguments` variable of the function and passing in an indeterminate amount of parameters instead of an array?